# Collection Navigation property not Refreshed (reload) after Edit

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I use a function to load data for a datagrid, Each row in the grid show items from a collection navigation property, But when I edit the collection and reload data for datagrid the added or removed entries not showing it shows only old ones:
Here is a part of LoadData() function I use for refreshing datagrid data, I call this after editing collection (Note the collection is correctly saved to DB):

```
count = query.Count();
    
var resumes0 = query.Skip(args.Skip.Value).Take(args.Top.Value).ToList<Resume>();
resumes0.ForEach(r =>
{
    context.Entry(r).Navigation("ResumeSkills").IsLoaded = false;
    context.Entry(r).Collection(r => r.ResumeSkills).IsLoaded = false;
    context.Entry(r).Collection(r => r.ResumeSkills).Load();            
});
resumes = resumes0;
```

Comment: What is the type of the variable `resumes` and what is the relationship between `resumes` and `context.Entry(r)`?

Comment: resumes is List<Resume>, Context.Entry(r), r is a Resume.

Comment: AsNoTracking() solved my problem, but I need to use Tracking entities.

Comment: `context.ChangeTracker.Clear()` before reloading.

Answer (score 0):

AsNoTracking() here:

```
var query = context.Resumes.Include(r => r.AcceptedResumes).Include(r => r.ResumeSkills).ThenInclude(rs => rs.Skill).AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
```

solved my problem, But I need tracking entities. But it seems this is the only way to solve this problem.